# Unable to view custom man file on MacOS

Tags: macos, macos-big-sur, manpage

I added a man file in man path but when I'm trying to read through man command; I'm getting "No Manual entry for command".

O/P of man --path

```
/opt/local/share/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:/Library/Apple/usr/share/man:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/share/man:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/man:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/share/man
```

O/P of man /usr/local/share/man/man1/speedtest.5.gz

```
    SPEEDTEST()                                                        SPEEDTEST()

Name
       speedtest  - Speedtest CLI by Ookla is the official command line client
       for testing the speed and performance of your internet connection.

Version
       1.0.0

Synopsis
           speedtest [-aAbBfhiIpPsv] [--ca-certificate=path] [--format=[=format-
type]] [--help] [--interface=interface]
           [--ip=ip_address] [--output-header] [--precision=num_decimal_places] 
[--progress=yes|no]
           [--selection-details] [--server-id=id] [--servers] [--unit=[=unit-of-
measure]] [--version]

Description
       speedtest is an application that measures the latency,  jitter,  packet
       loss,  download  bandwidth, and upload bandwidth of the network connec-
       tion between the client and a nearby Speedtest Server.
.......
```

O/P of man speedtest

```
No manual entry for speedtest
```

Please help.

**Update:** The issue was due to usage of section 5 suffix in section 1 directory. Renamed the man file to speedtest.1.gz and it works. Thanks @Mark Setchell for helping.

Comment: I wonder if you have confused it by putting section 5 suffix in section 1 directory, i.e. `/usr/local/share/man/man1/speedtest.5.gz` Maybe try choosing one or the other and sticking to it.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. Renamed to section 1 suffix and it works. :)

Comment: Cool - you can write it up as an answer and mark it as correct and bag the points...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the section 5 suffix to section 1 as the man file is in section 1 directory.